# Vim: how to start vim with a command without opening new buffer?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin

I recently upgraded to neovim & I love it. One of things I start to use is the Fugitive plugin, which I really like.

In order to use it as a replacement for `git gui`, I created a `bash` alias, to run `G` in the current dir: `alias G=nvim -c G`.

**Issue**: however, the issue is that the vim/nvim always opens a new empty buffer (which I do not want) as well as the fugitive split (which I do).

**Question:** Is there a way to only run the `G` command (or any other), without opening the default new buffer? Or maybe closing the newly opened buffer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have *only* the current window, use the `only` command.

```bash
alias G='nvim -c G -c only'
```

I tested with good ol' vim but it was confirmed to work with nvim.

Documentation on `only` can be found with `:h :only`. It's the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (i.e. "make this **W**indow the **O**nly one").

Comment: thanks works for `nvim` as well. Just for the reference, can you tell me where this `only` command is documented?

Comment: @JoeM. thanks for confirmation and for accepting my answer. I included documentation. It's always `:h whatever` :)